# cannot convert value of type NSMutableDictionary to expected argument type '[NSObject:AnyObject]?'

Tags: swift

I want to add BarCode Reader into my project but i got some problems when i tried.
Here i have give the error code, how to solve this please any one help me for solve this issue.

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)  //-----> In this line i have a error.
```

Comment: I got a type mismatch exactly like this when I used the *Convert to latest Swift Syntax* tool in Xcode 7.1 :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating an `NSMutableDictionary`, but the `NSError` init method has been updated to accept native Swift dictionaries. Try this:

```
var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either native swift dictionary as suggested by Pascal or just cast it to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`

```
error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject : AnyObject] )
```